# how can i fix git runner failed issue when building an docker image

Tags: reactjs, deployment, build, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner

When building an image, I manage the base image and the custom image separately. and this is offline environment.
Base image is directly inputted by command to build

and push, and custom image is managed through the GitLab Runner pipeline.

The problem is that the following error occurs when running the build-image pipeline.
(In Local, it builds normally and in package.json, it's version is 'init')

error

```
STEP 5/7: RUN yarn run build
yarn run v1.22.19
react-script-build
Creating an optiomized production build...
Failed to compile.
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/material' in '/app/src/components' 
error Command failed with exit code 1
Error: error building at STEP "RUN yarn run build": error while running runtime"exit staus1
```

dockerfile.base

```
FROM image-registry.apps.{url}.com/fep/react-base-nodev18.14-alpine:init
WORKDIR /app
COPY src ./src
COPY public ./public
RUN yarn run build
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["yarn", "serve", "build"]
```

docekrfile.origin

```
FROM nodev18.14-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile --offline
RUN yarn run build
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["yarn", "serve", "build"]
```

docekrfile

```
FROM image-registry.apps.{url}.com/fep/react-base-nodev18.14-alpine:init
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
COPY src ./src
COPY public ./public
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["yarn", "serve", "build"]
```

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
before_script:
 - source_%FEP_ADMIN_FRONT_FILE

stages:
 - set-version
 - pr-check
 - build-image
 - tag-image
 - push-image
 - deploy

variables:
 FEP_ADMIN_FRONT_FILE: ./variables
 FEP_ADMIN_FRONT_APP: fep_admin_frontend

set-version: 
 stage: set-version
 before-script: 
  - echo "setting version via package.json!"
 script: 
  - FEP_ADMIN_FRONT_VER=${jq -r .version package.json}
  - echo "export FEP_ADMIN_FRONT_VER=$FEP_ADMIN_FRONT_VER" > $FEP_ADMIN_FRONT_FILE
 artifacts:
  paths:
   - $FEP_ADMIN_FRONT_FILE

pr-check:
  stage: pr-ceck
  before_script:
  - oc login -u {//login info}
  - podmain login -u {//login info}

build-image
  stage: build-image
  script: 
  - podman build -t $FEP_ADMIN_FRONT_APP:$FEP_ADMIN_FRONT_VER .

(... omission)
```

I tried below

1. Base image build, tag, push(normally success)

> podman build -t react-base-nodev18:14-alpine:init -f Dockerfile.base

> podman tag localhost/react-base-nodev18.14-alpine:init image-registry.apps.{url}.com/fep/react-base-nodev18.14-alpine:init

> oc login ... (omit)

> podman push image-registry.apps.{url}.com/fep/react-base-nodev18.4-alpine:init

2. run the pipeline (error)

> gitlab-runner run

-> error
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/material' in '/app/src/components'
error Command failed with exit code 1